# SQL Server ADO.NET simultaneous select queries grievance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net, .net-4.5

I got 10 select queries with nolock hint used in one `SqlConnection`. This gives me 10 `SqlCommand` objects.

I advance each pointer in parallel according to some business rules so I cannot fetch all data from query 1, close it, and go with the next and so on.

One of my queries contains a max and group by clause.

- If I put in the 2nd or third position, it works ok.
- If I put it lastly, I get a timeout.

I've messed with `ConnectionTimeout` to no avail.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

After much reading, I reached the following conclusion : there was not enough memory on the db server to serve my app in a timely way.

I went to the DBA which did not find any error messages in the logs :(.

Is there a way to tell me what memory is consumed by a given query ? SQL Server Profiler gives me the number of reads/Writes, Duration but not the memory consumed by the results of a query.

thanks :)